# Why I get different result when running from CMD, than running from web service? (wkhtmltopdf)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-3.1, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using this code to generate a pdf file:

```
private async Task<byte[]> GerarPDF(string html, string chaveArquivo, string caminhoSalvar, string urlHeader, string urlFooter)
    {
        var caminhoPdf = $@"{caminhoSalvar}\{chaveArquivo}.pdf";

        string htmlTemporario = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".html");
        File.WriteAllText(htmlTemporario, html);

        var parametros = " -q -s A4 --load-error-handling ignore ";

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(urlHeader))
            parametros += $@" --header-html {urlHeader} ";

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(urlFooter))
            parametros += $@" --footer-html {urlFooter} ";


        parametros += $@" {htmlTemporario} {caminhoPdf} && {caminhoPdf} ";

        var processo = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = Path.Combine(DiretorioWK, WK),
                Arguments = parametros,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                WorkingDirectory = DiretorioWK,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            }
        };

        processo.Start();

        string error = processo.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

        processo.WaitForExit();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
        {
            throw new Exception(error);
        }



        var byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(caminhoPdf);

        File.Delete(htmlTemporario);

        return byteArray;

    }

}
```

This code results in a process that executes this command line:

```
wkhtmltopdf.exe  -q -s A4 --load-error-handling ignore  --header-html https://SomeSite.com.br C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\615f7abf-dd64-4b6f-b76c-7a58d9f0793e.html C:\Contratos\Declaracoes\D38D200D.pdf && C:\Fiap\Updown\Contratos\Declaracoes\D38D200D.pdf
```

When I execute that command line in CMD the pdf is created perfectly with one page, but when I execute from the API the pdf is generated with the correct page and another 2 white pages with only the header.

Why the pdf is being generated with this two extra pages?

EDIT 1:

Exact Value of parametros: `$@" -q -s A4 --load-error-handling ignore  --header-html https://SomeSite.com.br C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\615f7abf-dd64-4b6f-b76c-7a58d9f0793e.html C:\Contratos\Declaracoes\D38D200D.pdf && C:\Fiap\Updown\Contratos\Declaracoes\D38D200D.pdf "`

Comment: What is the _exact_ value of `parametros`?

Comment: Exact value of parametros: `$@" -q -s A4 --load-error-handling ignore  --header-html https://SomeSite.com.br C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\615f7abf-dd64-4b6f-b76c-7a58d9f0793e.html C:\Contratos\Declaracoes\D38D200D.pdf && C:\Contratos\Declaracoes\D38D200D.pdf "`

Comment: What does the `&&` mean? I think you are using it to launch the PDF? What happens if you remove that, then launch the PDF after the `WaitForExit` call?

Comment: @mjwills I removed the && and the path after it and it worked, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `&&` and the path after it and it worked, thanks